# Site not centered using Bootstrap on Mobile phone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

[image: Site not centered]

I'm using Bootstrap 3, I'm not exactly sure why is offsetting to the 
right.

```html
<div class="container">
   <div id="content">
    <a href="/winning-films">
       <div class="text-center banner">Check out the 2015 Salt Flats Film winners!!!</div>
    </a>
     <div class="row"> 
      <div id="main-page">
       <h2>SALT FLATS FILM FESTIVAL</h2>
       <div class="center-slider">
        <?php include_once('jssor_slider.php')?>
       </div>
       <h3>Presented by</h3>
       <a href="http://www.kidsfindjoy.org">
       <img class="img-responsive center center-block" src= "/img/joy-logo.jpg">
       </a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Is there someway to center the div with the container class on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the exact code, but as a general strategy inspect the page with something like chrome developer tools and see which element(s) are wider than the viewport, and thus widening the width or their parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Here I have changed the order of the div with the class text-center banner, the `<a></a>` tag must be inside the div.

```
<div class="cointainer">
  <div id="content">

    <div class="text-center banner"><a href="/winning-films">Check out the 2015 Salt Flats Film winners!!!</a></div>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="main-page">
        <h2>SALT FLATS FILM FESTIVAL</h2>
        <div class="center-slider">
          <!--?php include_once('jssor_slider.php')?-->
        </div>
        <h3>Presented by</h3>
        <a href="http://www.kidsfindjoy.org"><img class="img-responsive center center-block" src="/img/joy-logo.jpg"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The second suggest is to verify to use this line in your html head  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
this will help you to center your page on load and disable zoom and scroll

The third suggest is to use [Pingendo](http://pingendo.com), if you are a new developer, this tool will help you to generate a beautiful view or interface with Bootstrap, and you will see the HTML code and CSS3 live when you draft elements of bootstrap to your view.

Regards!